# Chrome background position doesn't work

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, background-position

Check the top big image with hovering your mouse: http://www.silviaalessandro.com/negozio/borsa3-2

The magnifier works fine in every browser except Google Chrome.

jQuery updating fine the background position:

> ```
>   plg.magny.css({
>     left: e.pageX,
>     top: e.pageY,
>     backgroundPosition: Math.round(plg.options.bgLeftModifier+origX)+'px '+Math.round(plg.options.bgTopModifier+origY)+'px'
>   });
> ```

I see on the Chrome developer tab that the magnifier background position changing, but Chrome fail to render it. When you scroll into(which change the magnifier size), the background position get updated.

What could be the problem?

Comment: this can't be our only code right? where is the rest?

Comment: As I noticed the template contains that background slider. If that is hidden everything works fine with the backgroun-position. Class of that slider element: avia_fullscreen_slider Just delete that element and try it out.

Comment: It seems like there is problem with the background-position when it is over a node which has the -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; CSS property... strange...

Comment: And also that huge background canvas disables the background position render in Chrome. What do you think, why that happens?